# react-native paper button vector-icons float right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I try to build an accordeonmenu with chevron icons my headerbutton has following code:

```
const AccordeonHeader = (Props) => {
        return(
            <View style={[accordionStyles.header]}>
                    <Button
                        contentStyle={[accordionStyles.header__button, ]}
                        color='black'
                        onPress={() => {show !== Props.value ? setShow(Props.value) : setShow(false)}}
                    >   
                        <Text
                            style={[accordionStyles.header__text, styles.headline__h2]}
                        >
                            {Props.label}
                        </Text>
                            
                        <Icon 
                            iconStyle={[accordionStyles.header__icon,]} 
                            name={show === Props.value ? "chevron-up" : "chevron-down"}
                        >
                        </Icon>  
                                           
                    </Button>
                </View>
        );
    }
```

with this styles

```
const accordionStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {

    },
    header__button: {
        width:'100%',
        borderColor:'green',
        borderWidth:2,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
    },
    header__text: {
        display:'none',
        color:'black',
    },
    header__icon: {
        alignSelf:'flex-end',
        color:'black',
    },
   
  });
```

but i can't get the icon on the rigth side and the text stay on the left.
its alwayse directly beside.
[image: accordeonb header button with text and icon]

Comment: add display: 'flex' to .header__button
you can also remove alignSelf property from .header__icon

Comment: @Anees it chages nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,Button,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import FontAwesome from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={[accordionStyles.header]} onPress={()=>console.log("press")}>        
          <Text style={{paddingTop:5}}>Sortieren</Text>
          <FontAwesome
            iconStyle={[accordionStyles.header__icon]}
            size={30}
            color="#000000" 
            name={"chevron-up"}
          />        
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const accordionStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: { 
    width: "100%",
  borderColor: "green",
  borderWidth: 2,
  flexDirection: "row",
  justifyContent: "space-between"},  
  header__icon: {
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    color: "black"
  }
});
```

[image]

[Code on snack](https://snack.expo.io/iGHyNj1qk)

Comment: not exactly now its the problem that the button is only the blue one but i also want to click on the chevron and the onpress of the button is executetd so the chevron has to be in the button

Comment: I have update my answer,  you just change the view to `TouchableOpacity` then can press whole line. Or use the old one you could change the color setting as you want.

Comment: Or if you just want chevron could click, just change back to view and add a `TouchableOpacity ` out side the icon. it's same.

Answer (score 2):

its Very Simple just add ,

```
contentStyle={{flexDirection: 'row-reverse'}}
```

and our icon moves to right side

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).